# What does this dput message mean?

Tags: ppa, packaging, launchpad, dput

I uploaded a new package to a PPA (the PPA contains *no* reference of any uploads of this package in the past), and `dput` output this curious message:

> Package includes an .orig.tar.gz file although the debian revision suggests
>   that it might not be required. Multiple uploads of the .orig.tar.gz may be
>   rejected by the upload queue management software.

I took the debian packaging for this package and uploaded the exact same version, properly tweaked, to a PPA. Hence the `changelog` contains two entries for the same version, but with different version suffix.

Now I'm confused because (1) I have never uploaded this package before to this PPA, (2) I got no email confirming the upload of the package, (3) nor an email informing me that the upload failed, and (4) there is no trace of the uploaded package on Launchpad. The `dput` output ended with:

> Successfully uploaded packages.

What is going on? Should I re-upload the package?

Comment: Don't know what ultimately happened, but now I tried to re-upload the exact same package, and it just worked...

Comment: Could you add the file names of upstream source archive, debian package and debian source change? It  is reproducible?